# JasperException does not appear in log4j file

Tags: spring, log4j

I have a website built with Spring, and a logging engine with Log4J. Everything is logged fine, except errors in JSP like this one:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /views/user/registration_form.jsp (line: 80, column: 107)
```

The error appears in the Eclipse console, but not in the log4j default files. Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT** :
My log4j configuration file:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, infofile, errorfile, stdout

# Log "INFO" messages to a log file
log4j.appender.infofile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.infofile.File=/Library/apache-tomcat-8.0.9/logs/info.log
log4j.appender.infofile.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.infofile.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.infofile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.infofile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.infofile.threshold=INFO

# Log "ERROR" messages to a log file
log4j.appender.errorfile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.errorfile.File=/Library/apache-tomcat-8.0.9/logs/error.log
log4j.appender.errorfile.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.errorfile.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.errorfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.errorfile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.errorfile.threshold=ERROR

# Log "INFO" messages to the console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.stdout.threshold=INFO

log4j.logger.org.springframework.integration.expression.ExpressionUtils=ERROR
# Hibernate
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO, hb
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql.ast.AST=info
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=warn
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql=debug
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.cache=info
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc=debug
```

**EDIT 2** : more precisely, we are able to handle ANY exception in our Spring MVC application, except those thrown by the view page (JasperException for example).

Comment: Could you please post your log4j configuration file?  Also - are you deploying to Tomcat?

Comment: I edited the question with my log4j config, and yes I am deploying to Tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to try would be to configure `org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` to handle JasperException (or any kind for that matter?).
Strangely I could not get it to work (it doesn't seem to be involved at all in the stack).

Something of the sort:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver"
    p:defaultErrorView="uncaughtException">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key=".AccessDeniedException">error403</prop>
            <prop key=".DataAccessException">error500</prop>
            <prop key=".NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException">error404</prop>
            <prop key=".TypeMismatchException">error404</prop>
            <prop key=".MissingServletRequestParameterException">error404</prop>
            <prop key=".TimeoutException">errorTimeout</prop>
            <prop key=".JasperException">error500</prop>

        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="warnLogCategory"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver" />
    <property name="defaultStatusCode" value="500" />
</bean>
```

If that isn't enough, you can always specify your own extension of `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver`.

Now if that doesn't work at all (it did not for me), you can provide your own `javax.servlet.Filter` and that will for sure work (though may not be the "spring-est" way).

Something like:

```
public class MyExceptionHandlerFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

public void doFilter(javax.servlet.ServletRequest request, javax.servlet.ServletResponse response, javax.servlet.FilterChain chain) throws java.io.IOException ,javax.servlet.ServletException {
    try {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // do something with the exception here...
    }
}
```

}

In a Spring 3/4 Java Config, you could put that class above in a @Configuration class like so:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
  ...
  @Bean
  public Filter exceptionSink() {
    return new MyExceptionHandlerFilter();
  }
  ...
}
```

(There's really a thousand ways to do it in Spring...as usual).
And if you're using `web.xml`, it'd look like this:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ExceptionHandlerFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.test.MyExceptionHandlerFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
...
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ExceptionHandlerFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

If you can provide a stacktrace of the error, it might shed some light on your filter chain (would be looking for any "springframework" classes in there) to see if there could be a less verbose/more spring-ish way to go about it. The chain will be different depending on your config (e.g. might see some spring-security filters in there if you're using it, etc.).

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try this and rate your answer if it works!

Comment: Neither? The later should really catch it all. As I said earlier, if you can provide the full stacktrace of your JasperException that should help. Also, what's your setup? Spring 3? XML or Java Config? etc.

Comment: Just stumbled upon a great entry on spring.io about MVC exceptions:
https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc
It details all possible ways to go about exception handling in a Spring Boot-MVC setup.

Comment: More precisely, we are able to handle ANY exception in our Spring MVC application, except those thrown by the view page (JasperException for example).

Comment: We were finally able to catch the Jasper exception with a custom JasperExceptionHandleFilter (implementing a javax.servlet.Filter) that throws a custom JasperException. Thanks @lpezet

Answer (score 0):

I think the JasperExecption is being written to STDERR, which is probably why they are showing up in your eclipse console log.  Can you see the messages in the catalina.out log file (/logs/catalina.yyyy-mm-dd.out)?

You could try adding the following to your errorfile appender config to capture the messages in your error log.

```
log4j.appender.errorfile.Target=System.err
```